# Java8 - How to store value from forEach in global variable ( lambda forEach )

Tags: lambda, java-8

Am trying to iterate an ArrayList using Java 8 - Lambda forEach and to store the value in the global variable.

Am getting the error like `type mis-match` and am not able to typecast also.

Please see my code below.

```
Long product_id = listProducts.forEach(listproducts ->listproducts.getId());
```

My Previous approach : (without JAVA8 feature, now i want to change my code by using Java8)

```
 for(Product prod : listProducts)
        {
            product_id=prod.getId();
        }
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. What exactly do you expect the output to be. You are processing a list of elements and seem to require a single value as the output.

Comment: Yes., it want to get a single value out of the list. previously i was using old method. But, just want to convert my code with new Java8 feactures.  I will update my old code too.

Comment: Why do you use a loop in your original code? All but the final value assigned to `product_id` will be overwritten.

Comment: you may use like Long product_id = listProducts.get(listProducts.size()-1).getId();
no need any loop for this purpose.

Comment: You should fix the logic errors of your code first, then you may think about expressing the actual intent using a different API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Long prod[] = new Long[1];
listProducts.forEach(product->{         
    prod[0] = product.getId();      
});

Long product_id = prod[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

sYou can not extract one single value from a list of values without aggregating it (max, min, sum, ...). In your old code you always saved the last id of your list of products. Is this intended? If so a loop does not make any sense. You can just retrieve the last element:

```
Long product_id = listProducts.get(listProducts.size() - 1);
```

But if you want to map the products to a list of their ids you can do something like:

```
List<Long> productIds = listProducts.stream().map(prod -> prod.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**UPDATE:**
Or to get a single ID (if list is empty, the productId is null):

```
Long productId = listProducts.stream().map(prod -> prod.getId()).reduce((id1, id2) -> id2).orElse(null);
```